# Retrieve CPU Utilization for a Process

Tags: java, linux

I want to modify the below script to only run if the process/pid number is utilizing over 50% of the CPU.  Anyone know how to get that information?  I would like to only create a thread dump using jstack if the cpu utilization is over 50% for a particular pid.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 "Usage: jstackSeries  [  [  ] ]"
    echo >&2 "    Defaults: count = 10, delay = 1 (seconds)"
    exit 1
fi

pid=$1          # required
count=${2:-10}  # defaults to 10 times
delay=${3:-1} # defaults to 1 second

while [ $count -gt 0 ]
do
    jstack $pid >jstack.$pid.$(date +%H%M%S.%N)
    sleep $delay
    let count--
    echo -n "."
done
```

Comment: `ps` with `-p` to specify the pid you're interested in and appropriate  `-o` format specifiers (specficially, `%cpu`) can be used to obtain CPU load percentages. See `man ps` for more details. 
(Example: 'ps -p  14557 -o%cpu` currently displays 1.7 on my Linux machine; that process happens to be an inactive copy of Firefox.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use specific options for ps to extract the cpu utilization. For example:

```
if [ `ps -o cp= -p $pid` -ge 500 ]; then
        jstack $pid >jstack.$pid.$(date +%H%M%S.%N)
fi
```

The `ps` command used above specifies a custom output format (`-o`). `cp` is the percent cpu (cputime/realtime) times 10. `=` sepcifies no header for the `cp`. As there are no headers for any column (all one of them) there will be no header line. `-p $pid` selects the pid to retrieve info for. The result of the ps command will be one line with a integer between 0 and 1000 for 0% and 100%.

Note that cputime/realtime may not be exactly what you want so look at the man page for ps.